# Gott Goldberg Vanderbei projection using R

Tags: coordinate-system, r

I want to know if it is possible to use R to generate a double sided disk projection  discussed in https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.08176v1 . I am not familiar with GIS softwares but comfortable with R. Using natural earth data from https://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/50m/raster/HYP_50M_SR_W.zip, I tried Robinson projection which works as expected.

```
library(stars)
library(tmap)
read_stars("./HYP_50M_SR_W/HYP_50M_SR_W.tif") -> wm
tm_shape(wm, projection = "+proj=robin",raster.warp = FALSE) +
tm_rgb(style ="cont")
```

How can I use the projection mentioned in the above paper instead of Robinson?

(My purpose is to get the map printed for my daughter, may be cut into jigsaw puzzle pieces. I think the projection discussed in the paper would give a more realistic view)